# Can I use the Winkler method as a way to measure the rate of photosynthesis?

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis

I want to make an investigation where I measure how the color of light affects the rate of photosynthesis.

The idea is to put an Elodea plant in a test tube and shine with different color of light during time. I want to measure the dissolved oxygen in the beaker every minute for 5 minutes for different colors. As I have no access to a dissolved oxygen sensor I thought I could take out different samples of water every minute and separate them in bottles to conduct the Winkler method on each one. Hence, calculating the mg/L of dissolved oxygen and make a line of best fit for each color.

Is this a functioning idea? Could I get feedback?